# J2ME Emulator error

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, java-me

I have built mobile application that contain lots of pictures and videos

the problem is everything In my code seems fine but I have this error when I run the emulator

((The application can not be lunched . The application may have done an illegal operation . Contact the application provider to resolve the issue 139))

What does this error supposed to mean ??

I have reviewed my code 10 times , I couldn't find any error !!

unfortunately , I couldn't post my code here because it is very huge !!

So , If you just tell me this error associated with with section in the program , that would be great !

Thanks

Comment: Is there a stack trace with the error?

Comment: No, actually this error appears on the emulator itself , no error on the compiler has been issued !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All , I found that this error occur when the class object represents an abstract class, an interface, an array class, a primitive type, or void , and by mistake I define my class as abstract !

Comment: Nice to know you found a solution.  Best of luck with this.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of error messages are often related to non-supported JAD/MANIFEST attributes.

Try removing all non-standard attributes from your JAD and MANIFEST.